# Copy worksheet by specifying its index does not work

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a worksheet to another workbook specifying an index, but it does not work.
When I type the sheet name, it works. I would like to know why specifying index number does not work.

```
Dim targetWb As Workbook
Dim targetSh As Worksheet
Dim sourceWb As Workbook
Dim sourceSh As Worksheet

Set targetWb = Workbooks.Open(Targetfilename)
Set targetSh = targetWb .Sheets("Sheet1")

Set sourceWb = Workbooks.Open(Sourcefilename)

'Specify the index of the sheet here 
'When specifying its sheet name, it works
Set sourceSh = sourceWb.Sheets(2)

targetSh.Activate
sourceSh.Copy After:=targetSh
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work?  Get an error or doesn't copy the correct one?  How many sheets does the source wb have?

Comment: @ACCtionMan it does not get any errors. When executing the macro, it finishes without error but it does not copy and paste the sheet to the target file. The source file has 13 sheets.

Comment: Does `sourceWb` have hidden sheets? What does `Debug.Print sourceWb.Sheets("Sheetname").Index` return in the Immediate Window?

Comment: I just duplicated your code with two of my own workbooks and it worked, so not sure what happened with yours.  If you do ``Debug.Print sourceWb.Sheets(2).Name`` do you get the intended sheetname?

Comment: Note that `Sheets` and `Worksheets` have different countings. While `Sheets` conains **all** kind of sheets (worksheets, chart sheets, etc) `Worksheets` only contains worksheets! Also note that the index is the **position** of the tab in the sheets tab bar below the sheets and has nothing to do with the sheets's name. So `Sheets("Sheet1")` can be the same sheet as `Sheets(2)` if `Sheet1` is the second sheet in the tab bar.

Comment: Do you have an `On Error Resume Next` somewhere before this snippet? There should be an error e.g. if there is no `"Sheet1"` or `Sheets(2)`. Could you share the complete code?